# How to subscribe for changes made on CKShare?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I need to know about:

- when the record IS NOT shared with me anymore
- when permissions was changed from `readwrite` to only `read`

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5):

Oh, answer is simple:

```
let shareSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "cloudkit.share", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
```

Works only for private database, in other words for the **OWNER** of shared records, for users who created CKShare.

If you need to subscribe for changes from the other side. For users participating in this share (invited to that share) you need to simply create `CKDatabaseSubscription`.

```
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "pl.blue-world.fieldservice.sharedDatabase")
subscription.database = sharedDatabase
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how a user participating in the share can be notified if they are **removed** from the share? It seems they get a notification if they are subscribed to the shared database, but the notification doesn’t contain any records or any other indication that they no longer have access.

Comment: I posted my question here in case you happen to know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788219/how-to-be-notified-if-the-owner-removes-me-from-a-ckshare-on-cloudkit